# Iptables: allow wget

Tags: linux, iptables, wget

for some reason the following rules block `wget`.

```
 iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

 iptables -A INPUT -j DROP

 iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

What rules I need to add to allow wget?

Comment: Try to enable just INPUT rules and see if it works. Then do same with OUTPUT. It will be much easier to find what is blocking it.

Comment: The --dport for 80,22 on INPUT **should do ** nothing as the incoming connection for wget is related or established.  wget connects to port 80 on the other end but gets a random port number on our end.

Comment: add this and see if it does anything.  iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 2):

There is no need whatsoever for OUTPUT iptables rules. You can check it yourself, most intros to the use of the *iptables* do not even mention any such rule. You should drop them altogether, then *wget* will work.

For instance, it makes no sense to have an *ESTABLISHED,RELATED* rule for outgoing packets, if it is you starting the connections.

Specifically, the reason why *wget* is failing is that you have made no allowance for *DNS*, thus where is no name resolution on your system: you are blocking all such requests.

Also, you should keep in mind that wget is capable of downloading pages not just through the HTTP protocol, but also HTTPS, FTP, and so on. Thus, strictly speaking, there is no such thing as a wget port, there are only the ports used by the protocols *wget* knows. And you are only allowing HTTP, thus strongly inhibiting wget's usefulness.